# C++ typedef with nested templates is not a class, struct, or union type

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename

I'm not sure to understand why the following code is not compiled with g++:

```
t.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Distrib<double>’:
t.cpp:28:56:   instantiated from ‘Sampler<Distrib<Solution<double> > >’
t.cpp:35:48:   instantiated from here
t.cpp:16:45: erreur: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
t.cpp:18:43: erreur: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

I was expecting to be able to propagate the `AtomType` type across the nested templates…

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Solution
{
    public:
        typedef T AtomType;
};

template<typename SOLT>
class Distrib
{
    public:
        typedef typename SOLT::AtomType AtomType;
        typedef std::vector<AtomType> Matrix;

        Matrix matrix;
};

template<typename DT>
class Sampler
{
    public:
        typedef typename DT::AtomType AtomType;
        typedef typename Distrib<AtomType>::Matrix Matrix;

        Matrix matrix;
};

int main()
{
    Sampler< Distrib< Solution<double> > > sampler;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Sampler` class, you have:

```
typedef typename Distrib<AtomType>::Matrix Matrix;
```

Here, `AtomType` is `double`, so this is

```
typedef typename Distrib<double>::Matrix Matrix;
```

And then in your `Distrib` class, the line

```
typedef typename SOLT::AtomType AtomType;
```

expands to

```
typedef typename double::AtomType AtomType;
```

Hence the error message. I think you want the line in the `Sampler` class to be:

```
typedef typename DT::Matrix Matrix;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `Distrib` template you have the following `typedef`

```
typedef typename SOLT::AtomType AtomType;
```

Which means that any type you pass in as a template parameter, must have a `AtomType` as a member, and `double` has no such thing.

If you made a class like so

```
class Double
{
   typedef myType AtomType;
};
```

and passed that in as a template parameter to your `Distrib` template, it would compile, as `Double::AtomType` does exist.

Comment: Note that OP is passing `Solution<double>` as a parameter to `Distrib` yet the error is the same as if a `double` itself were passed.

Comment: That still won't compile, and would be wrong even if it did. The problem is using `AtomType` as the template argument for `Distrib`, which expects some kind of `Solution`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Matrix` typedef in the `Distrib` class is using `AtomType`, but what we would expect was a `DT`:

```
typedef typename Distrib<DT>::Matrix Matrix;
```

The compiler was seeing the `double` propagated across nested templates.

Comment: I think you don't really need the typedef for `AtomType` to be able to declare a matrix in `Sampler`. You can simply say `typedef typename DT::Matrix matrix;`, no?

Comment: No, `Distrib` expects a `Solution`, not another `Distrib`. We don't have one, but since `DT` is a `Distrib` we don't need one - it should probably be `typedef typename DT::Matrix matrix;`

Answer (score 1):

`Distrib` is templated over the type of `Solution`; but in the definition of `Sampler::Matrix` you're using `AtomType` as the template argument. Presumably, you just want the type of `Distrib` that was provided as to the `Sampler`:

```
template<typename DT>
class Sampler
{
    // ...
    typedef typename DT::Matrix Matrix;
};
```